# connecting windows instances using win_ping

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, winrm

I need to connect windows ec2 instances of aws using common username and password. Here is my ansible code :

```
      - win_ping:
        with_items: "{{ Ips }}"
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        ansible_ssh_port: 5986
        ansible_connection: winrm
        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

It showing error like "ERROR! 'ansible_connection' is not a valid attribute for a Task. When i pass this as variable file ,playbook itself running in port 5986.So how can i connect windows host with my user and password from linux using ansible??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your inventory in groups_vars or host_vars as suggested here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html.  You can't specify ansible_connection as a task attribute.

I would also suggest encrypting the file (also recommended in the link provided) so you don't have usernames and passwords laying around in plain text.

Comment: In my case iam not using any inventory,i just running my localhost only in hosts of the master playbook.yml like this hosts:localhost and using delegate_to iam using to run a task to that hosts.So how can i use group_vars here????

Comment: for that win_ping alone i need to set that winrm connection var and  winrm port to the host which i delegate_to.

Comment: You can add a localhost host_var file so solve that issue, but if you're only running with an implicit localhost then delegate_to doesn't have much meaning.

Comment: i have added now establishing winrm connection but showing timeout error,even i set connect_timeout and timeout.But still same.Like below: ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: usernametrial on PORT 5986 TO xx.xx.xx.xx
failed: [localhost] (item=xx.xx.xx.xx) => {"item": "xx.xx.xx.xx", "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3e65a50>, 'Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Have you verified you setup winrm correctly on your Windows target?  I would setup a hard coded trivial example and not use delegate_to to see if you can get it to work..

Comment: yeah , winrm connection enabled only.i checked it.But still same error

Comment: I can able to connect windows of that machine using rdp.But when iam using telnet its getting timeout.Also i checked in that machine winrm configurations and port 5985 and 5986 listening.

Comment: "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.13', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcb12024a90>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.13 timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
"unreachable": true...I can able to ping my windows machine and slo i enabled winrm by running this script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1.Still facing error.

Comment: RDP access and WinRM access are completely different.  Depending on your Windows version (W2k3, W2k8, W2k12)  there can be some intricacies.  The script provided here, https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1,  doesn't always work.  If you already had IIS running or had certificates on that machine things get messed up.  My advice is to either debug using the MSDN winrm reference or start with a fresh windows install.